# update_metadata is not working for me

Tags: wordpress

I'm trying to add  custom fields to my taxonomy, but when I'm saving values   update_metadata  function save nothing

```
add_action( 'product_category_edit_form_fields', 'edit_product_category', 10, 2);
function edit_product_category($tag, $taxonomy)
{
    $product_category_sort_field = get_metadata($tag->taxonomy, $tag->term_id, 'product_category_sort_field', true);
    ?>
    <tr class="form-field">
        <th scope="row" valign="top"><label for="product_category_sort_field">sort</label></th>
        <td>
            <input type="text" style="width:20%" name="product_category_sort_field" id="product_category_sort_field"
                value="<?php echo $product_category_sort_field; ?>"/><br />
        </td>
    </tr>
    <?php
}

add_action( 'edited_product_category', 'save_product_category', 10, 2);
function save_product_category($term_id, $tt_id)
{
    if (!$term_id) return;

    if ( isset( $_POST['product_category_sort_field'] ) ) {
        update_metadata($_POST['taxonomy'], $term_id, 'product_category_sort_field',
       $_POST['product_category_sort_field'] );
    }
}
```

Comment: Please, mind the code formatting when posting. See http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that there's no `wp_taxonomy_meta` table, so this doesn't work: `update_metadata($_POST['taxonomy'], ...`.

The two solutions I've seen: storing in `wp_options` or using the field description to store a JSON string.

Here, I'm using only *one* `wp_option`s field, but I'm not sure if this scales well if you have hundreds and hundreds of terms. Note that you we using the wrong hooks too.

```
add_action( 'product_edit_form_fields', 'edit_product_category', 10, 2);
function edit_product_category($tag, $taxonomy)
{ 
    $option = get_option('product_category_sort_field');
    $product_category_sort_field = ( $option && isset( $option[$tag->term_id] ) ) 
        ? $option[$tag->term_id] : '';
    ?>
    <tr class="form-field">
        <th scope="row" valign="top"><label for="product_category_sort_field">sort</label></th>
        <td>
            <input type="text" style="width:20%" name="product_category_sort_field" id="product_category_sort_field"
                value="<?php echo $product_category_sort_field; ?>"/><br />
        </td>
    </tr>
    <?php
}

add_action( 'edited_term_taxonomy', 'save_product_category', 10, 2);
function save_product_category( $term_id, $taxonomy )
{
    if (!$term_id) 
        return;

    $option = get_option('product_category_sort_field');

    if ( isset( $_POST['product_category_sort_field'] ) ) {
        $option[$term_id] = $_POST['product_category_sort_field'];
        update_option( 'product_category_sort_field', $option );
    }
}
```

You'll find many [relevant posts](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/search?q=add+custom+field+to+taxonomy) at WordPress Answers, like [this](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/29322/add-custom-taxonomy-fields-when-creating-a-new-taxonomy) and [this](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/56760/how-to-add-custom-fields-to-custom-taxonomies-in-wordpress-cleanly).

Comment: Your answer helped me a lot. Now everything works fine. Appreciate your reply, Thanks